# no se ejecuta shell unix desde java

Tags: java, shell, jsch

Hola tengo el siguiente código que se conecta a mi server *Linux(AIX 6.1)* y ejecuta un comando:

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


    /**
     * Clase encargada de establecer conexión y ejecutar comandos SSH.
     */
    public class SSHConnector {

        /**
         * Constante que representa un enter.
         */
        private static final String ENTER_KEY = " ";
        /**
         * Sesión SSH establecida.
         */
        private Session session;

        private static final String USERNAME = "user";
        private static final String HOST = "10.00.00";
        private static final int PORT = 22;
        private static final String PASSWORD = "pass";


        public void connect(String username, String password, String host, int port)
            throws JSchException, IllegalAccessException {
            if (this.session == null || !this.session.isConnected()) {
                JSch jsch = new JSch();

                this.session = jsch.getSession(username, host, port);
                this.session.setPassword(password);

                // Parametro para no validar key de conexion.
                this.session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

                this.session.connect();
            } else {
                throw new IllegalAccessException("Sesion SSH ya iniciada.");
            }
        }

            public final String executeCommand(String command)
            throws IllegalAccessException, JSchException, IOException {
            if (this.session != null && this.session.isConnected()) {

                // Abrimos un canal SSH. Es como abrir una consola.
                ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) this.session.
                    openChannel("exec");

                InputStream in = channelExec.getInputStream();

                // Ejecutamos el comando.
                channelExec.setCommand(command);
                channelExec.connect();

                // Obtenemos el texto impreso en la consola.
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String linea;

                while ((linea = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(linea);
                    builder.append(ENTER_KEY);
                }

                // Cerramos el canal SSH.
                channelExec.disconnect();

                // Retornamos el texto impreso en la consola.
                return builder.toString();
            } else {
                throw new IllegalAccessException("No existe sesion SSH iniciada.");
            }
        }
         public static void main(String[] args) {

            try {
                SSHConnector sshConnector = new SSHConnector();
               sshConnector.connect(USERNAME, PASSWORD, HOST, PORT);
                **String result = sshConnector.executeCommand("cd home/recauser/procesos/orquestador/bin;./startOrquestador.sh start");**

    // String result = sshConnector.executeCommand("hostname");

               sshConnector.disconnect();

               System.out.println(result);

           } catch (JSchException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();

                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();

                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
           } 
            catch (IOException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();

               System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
           }
        }
        /**
         * Cierra la sesión SSH.
         */
        public final void disconnect() {
            this.session.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

El código me funciona cuando lanzo un "*hostname*" o "*date*" pero si quiero ejecutar la *Shell*(variable result) no lo hace.

Vale decir que la conexión esta bien solo me falta que la *Shell* se ejecute.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia el comando a algo como esto:

```
sshConnector.executeCommand("cd /home/recauser/procesos/orquestador/bin && sh startOrquestador.sh start");
```

Comment: No funciona @Crack81

Comment: Me podrias decir exactamente que error te lanza?

Comment: No arroja Error, de echo aparece que lo ejecutara (BUILD SUCCESFUL), pero al revisar la app web donde se ven los resultados noto que no hace nada. @Crack81

Comment: lo solucione "cd /home/recauser/procesos/orquestador/bin/;./startOrquestador.sh start" había que colocar un / al final. Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné

```
"cd /home/recauser/procesos/orquestador/bin/;./startOrquestador.sh start"
```

había que colocar un / al final. Gracias por la ayuda!